# How to prove a number is algebraic?

Tags: real-analysis, algebraic-number-theory, real-numbers

Show that $\sqrt[3]{\sqrt 3+2} +4$ is an algebraic number

Comment: Hint: an algebraic number is a root of a polynomial with integer coefficient.

Comment: Find some polynomial with integer coefficients where this number is a solution. What happens if you put your number into the polynomial $((x -4)^3-2)^2-3$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard method: set $x=\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{3}+2}+4$. Now compute $(x-4)^3=\sqrt{3}+2$. So $[(x-4)^3-2]^2=3$ and you're done.